# question on force of interest with investment at 2 different times

Tags: finance

You invested    $500$ on Jan $1$ $2012$. To save for this amount, you invest $x$ on Jan $1$ $2008$ and $2x$ on July $1$ $2008$. The force of interest is $\delta_t=0.02t$ where $t$ is $0$ on Jan $1$ $2008$. Find $x$.

The accumulated value at $t_{\frac{1}{2}}=A(\frac{1}{2})=x(1+i)^{\frac{1}{2}}+2x$

$=x({e^{(\delta_t)}}^{0.5}+2x)(e^{\int^4_0 0.002t dt})$

This simplifies to

$500=(xe^{\sqrt{0.08}}+2x)(e^{0.16}-1)$

$\therefore x=866.17$

But the answer is $x=142.26$.

Comment: What interest rate $i$ are you using? Why are you using compound interest? Looking at the exercice I would think that you have to use continuous compounding. That is, your accumulated value $A(t)$ at time $t$ is given by
$$A(t) = x e^{0.01t^2},$$
where $x$ is the initial investment.

Comment: @Siron, isn't the force of interest $/delta$ equal to (1+i) in continuous compounding. What I have done I have calculated the future value at $t_{\frac{1}{2}}$. Then I find A(t) from time 0.5 to 4 However, I  shall try it your way also to see if it works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accumulation function is $$a(t)=a(t_0)\mathrm e^{\int_{t_0}^t\delta(s)\mathrm d s}=a(t_0)\mathrm e^{0.01(t^2-t_0^2)}$$
So the equation of value is
$$
a(t_0)\mathrm e^{0.01(t^2-t_0^2)}+a(t_1)\mathrm e^{0.01(t^2-t_1^2)}=500
$$
For $t_0=0$ we have $a(t_0)=x$ and $t_1=\frac{1}{2}$ we have $a(t_1)=2x$ and then
$$
x\left[\mathrm e^{0.01(4^2)}+2\mathrm e^{0.01(4^2-0.5^2)}\right]=500
$$
and then $$x=\frac{500}{3.514672}=142.26$$

Comment: Your second last equation seems wrong.  The result of this equation is not $142.6$. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x*%28+e%5E%280.01%284%5E2%29%29%2B2*+e%5E%280.01*%284%5E2-3.5%5E2%29%29%29+%3D500)

Comment: there was a typo 3.5 instead of 0.5. [Corrected](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x*%28+e%5E%280.01%284%5E2%29%29%2B2*+e%5E%280.01*%284%5E2-0.5%5E2%29%29%29+%3D500). thnx

Comment: You´re still active?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: The equation is

$$ \large{ \left( x\cdot e^{\int_0^{0.5} 0.02\cdot t \, dt}+2x\right)\cdot e^{\int_{0.5}^4 0.02\cdot t \, dt}=500 }$$